# Encoding Python object (with Python Convention) in JSON with Java naming convention

Tags: java, python, json, naming-conventions

I need to send an object from my Python project to my Java project by JSON encoding it.

However, according to **naming conventions**, python has fields like

```
variable_name
```

while Java has fields like

```
private String variableName
```

How to encode the python object with the above variable (variable_name) in JSON, so that I can decode that JSON object into a Java model (having field as variableName)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Jackson library, You can use :

```
@JsonProperty("variable_name") // same name come from python app
private String variableName;
```